# Is there any command like time, but for memory usage?

Tags: linux, memory, time, profiling

Is there any command like `time`, but that reports more statistics?  It would be great if I could do something like:

```
$ statistics some_command
time:
    real    0m3.002s
    user    0m0.000s
    sys     0m0.000s
memory:
    min     41K
    peak    2.5M
    mean    1.1M
. . .
```

If it could go even further, that would be great.  Right now, for debugging, I either end up staring intently at `top` (actually `glances`), or sprinkling statements all through my code.

If there was something that I could pass a command to, that would be fantastic.

**EDIT**

I might have found a solution: `perf` in the package `linux-tools` and `linux-tools-common` on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
$ perf stat ./someprocess
Performance counter stats for './someprocess':

      12007.384578 task-clock                #    0.996 CPUs utilized          
             1,092 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec                  
                16 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec                  
           295,102 page-faults               #    0.025 M/sec                  
    40,553,682,299 cycles                    #    3.377 GHz                     [83.33%]
    18,400,458,723 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   45.37% frontend cycles idle    [83.35%]
     8,356,832,355 stalled-cycles-backend    #   20.61% backend  cycles idle    [66.64%]
    56,930,684,595 instructions              #    1.40  insns per cycle        
                                             #    0.32  stalled cycles per insn [83.34%]
     9,083,443,825 branches                  #  756.488 M/sec                   [83.35%]
         3,431,737 branch-misses             #    0.04% of all branches         [83.33%]

      12.051963969 seconds time elapsed
```

([The page that helped.](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat))

Comment: There is no memory statistics in your `perf` results.

Comment: "like time but for memory" doesn't really make sense. What **exactly** do you want to know? Memory is not a measurement.

Comment: Are you looking to audit an application that you're making? If so, in what language?

Answer (score 51):

`zsh` has a more powerful built-in `time` command than `bash` has, and the `zsh` version can report memory statistics.

Even if you don't regularly use `zsh` as your day-to-day shell, you can just run it when you need to gather these kinds of statistics.

Set the `TIMEFMT` environment variable to indicate the output you want. Here is what I have in my `.zshrc` file (perhaps a bit too fancy, but I like it):

```
if [[ `uname` == Darwin ]]; then
    MAX_MEMORY_UNITS=KB
else
    MAX_MEMORY_UNITS=MB
fi

TIMEFMT='%J   %U  user %S system %P cpu %*E total'$'\n'\
'avg shared (code):         %X KB'$'\n'\
'avg unshared (data/stack): %D KB'$'\n'\
'total (sum):               %K KB'$'\n'\
'max memory:                %M '$MAX_MEMORY_UNITS''$'\n'\
'page faults from disk:     %F'$'\n'\
'other page faults:         %R'
```

(A complicated detail: On Linux, max memory is megabytes; on macOS it's in kilobytes. To get the value for `%M`, zsh calls `getrusage()`, and then uses [`ru_maxrss / 1024`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/c04a39187704e2b46a46f9aeee370365aeff4b1f/Src/jobs.c#L892). but on Linux, `ru_maxrss` is in kilobytes, and on Mac it's in bytes. See `man getrusage` on both platforms.)

Sample output:

```
% time ls
[... the output of ls, followed by:]
ls -G   0.00s  user 0.00s system 91% cpu 0.004 total
avg shared (code):         0 KB
avg unshared (data/stack): 0 KB
total (sum):               0 KB
max memory:                3 MB
page faults from disk:     0
other page faults:         337
```

Comment: Your answer helped me A LOT but I have a question: Is 'max memory' in MB? I believe it's KB or even B.

Comment: Glad it helped, @Andres. In my tests , 'max memory' is in MB, but you can test it yourself by compiling https://gist.github.com/mmorearty/fa34c0f29abe454fd14b and running it in zsh with e.g. `time malloc-bytes 10000000`. That will malloc 10 megabytes, so try it and then see what zsh reports.

Comment: According to [the zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html) `%M` is the maximum memory in megabytes.

Comment: `%M` reports in *kilobytes*

Comment: This is a great answer! But it needs a correction: `| M  | Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kilobytes.`

Comment: The Zsh docs were wrong about the unit of `%M` until 2018: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2018/msg00170.html

Answer (score 29):

[GNU time](http://www.gnu.org/software/time/) can report a bit more information than the version built into Bash; use `command time` rather than just `time` to invoke it, and see the man page or info for details.

Comment: Or call `/usr/bin/time -v ./my_command.sh`

Answer (score 8):

Based on Richard's answer, you can create an alias to use GNU time and provide average and maximum memory information:

```
alias time="$(which time) -f '\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys,\t%K amem,\t%M mmem'"
```

or adjust your environment:

```
export TIME='\t%E real,\t%U user,\t%S sys,\t%K amem,\t%M mmem'
```

But be aware that this only works for `/usr/bin/time` which is often not called by default.

From the man page:

> K Average total (data+stack+text) memory use of the process, in
> Kilobytes.
>
> M Maximum resident set size of the process during its
> lifetime, in Kilobytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/usr/bin/time` which is different from `time`.

Use it with `-v` and you may have what you want without any additional install.

Example:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v cat xxx.txt > /dev/null
    Command being timed: "cat xxx.txt"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 100%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2024
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 121
    Voluntary context switches: 0
    Involuntary context switches: 0
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```